# Angular2 typescript error initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular and the typescript version 2.7.1. I'm getting the following errors:

> "Initializers are not allowed in ambient context.
>   'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
>   Module D/Mean/CRUD/project/AngularApp/node_modules/rxjs/operators/index has no exported member 'toPromise'.

[image]

Comment: Please show us your code !

Comment: show the employee.component.ts where the error is pointing too

Comment: declare var M = any;

Comment: `declare var M = any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css'],
  providers: [EmployeeService]
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {`

Comment: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { toPromise } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Please don't add code as comments - edit your question to include the code

Comment: `declare var M : any`. You need to use a colon, not an equal sign, when you declare a variable's type

Comment: @PeterKim yeah.. I figured it.

Comment: Thanks @auburg. I have figured out the solutions, And its working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the issue.

The syntax for declaring the variable was the issue, I have used "=" instead of ":"

I have changed method to import "toPromise" from

import { toPromise } from 'rxjs/operators' to

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

These two fixed my errors.